# Why webservice not work in php?

Tags: php, web-services

I am using web service from HERE

but i am using php code for accessing

```
> <?php $user="test"; $pass="test"; $result=''; 
> try 
>     {
>     $client = new SoapClient('test',array(
>         'trace' => true, 
>       'exceptions' => true));
>        $result = $client-> CreateModifyNavCustomer('3030','Deved','Verman','B55','sixtyfive','Texas','201301','10','UP','97000000','012122222','email@email','2');
>      }     catch (SoapFault $e)    {
>        var_dump($e);
>      }  ?>
```

But output showing error

```
object(SoapFault)#2 (9) { ["message":protected]=> string(300) "SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://mail.australdynamics.com:3036/NAV2013ANL/WS/CRONUS Australia Pty. Ltd/Codeunit/WebFunctionsWriting' : failed to load external entity "http://mail.australdynamics.com:3036/NAV2013ANL/WS/CRONUS%20Australia%20Pty.%20Ltd/Codeunit/WebFunctionsWriting" " ["string":"Exception":private]=> string(0) "" ["code":protected]=> int(0) ["file":protected]=> string(27) "C:\xampp\htdocs\devua\1.php" ["line":protected]=> int(9) ["trace":"Exception":private]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(6) { ["file"]=> string(27) "C:\xampp\htdocs\devua\1.php" ["line"]=> int(9) ["function"]=> string(10) "SoapClient" ["class"]=> string(10) "SoapClient" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" ["args"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(105) "http://mail.australdynamics.com:3036/NAV2013ANL/WS/CRONUS Australia Pty. Ltd/Codeunit/WebFunctionsWriting" [1]=> array(2) { ["trace"]=> bool(true) ["exceptions"]=> bool(true) } } } } ["previous":"Exception":private]=> NULL ["faultstring"]=> string(300) "SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://mail.australdynamics.com:3036/NAV2013ANL/WS/CRONUS Australia Pty. Ltd/Codeunit/WebFunctionsWriting' : failed to load external entity "http://mail.australdynamics.com:3036/NAV2013ANL/WS/CRONUS%20Australia%20Pty.%20Ltd/Codeunit/WebFunctionsWriting" " ["faultcode"]=> string(4) "WSDL" }
```

Can anyone help me.

Comment: Please give us the whole error message if you have it? At a guess, either the service is broken or you're passing incorrect parameters to `$client-> CreateModifyNavCustomer()` but since it requires credentials and nobody here is likely to sign up (if possible) just to debug for you means, you're unlikely to get much help. Good luck

Comment: m updating my question with full error of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to send the user name and login when you create a soap client object,

secondly, try using a non wsdl mode.

```
     $user="test"; $pass="test"; $result='';
     try
         {
         $client = new SoapClient(null,
                                    array('location' => "test",
                                    'uri' => 'test',
                                    'login' => $user, 'password' => $pass, 'trace' => true,'exceptions' => true));
         $result = $client-> CreateModifyNavCustomer('3030','Deved','Verman','B55','sixtyfive','Texas','201301','10','UP','97000000','012122222','email@email','2');
         } catch (SoapFault $e)    {
            var_dump($e);
         }
```

Comment: thanks deepika...

can you tell me please in the output here lots of think showing... also working url... what we prefer for response...

Comment: there is some issue with the URL, i guess its not correct because var_dump($client->__getFunctions()); gives output as null, which means wsdl doesn't has any functions so you can't use CreateModifyNavCustomer()

Comment: actually this web service is based on window NAV. so i have to need to use NTLMStream